# How can I determine if a String equals a range of numbers in Java?

Tags: java

I receive input from the user that can be anything ranging from "0", "1", "2"... "F", "?", etc., and store this in a String.

How can I determine if what is stored in the string is a value from 1 to 8, without using 8 if statements?

It would look something like:

```
String[] inputArray = new String[3];
if (inputArray[2] == "[1 through 8]")
{
...
}
```

Comment: A regular expression test - with a character class including a range - would be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could try with regex like

   ```
   inputArray[2].matches("[0-9A-F]")
   ```
2. You could also use something like

   ```
   inputArray[2].length()==1 && "0123456789ABCDEF".condains(inputArray[2])
   ```
3. Or read first character via `char ch = inputArray[2].charAt(0)` (also make sure that `inputArray[2]` contains only one character) and see if it is in specified range `0-9` or `A-F` like

   ```
   ('0'<=ch && ch<='9') || ('A'<=ch && ch<='F')
   ```

Comment: I will use the first method. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a good way to convert a String contained in an array, for example stringArray[2], to a character?

Comment: @ZacharyKeener Test it and see if it works fine. My answer is based on assumption that your string should contain only one character in specified range, so if I was mistaken let me know and I will try to update my solutions.

Comment: @ZacharyKeener `char ch = inputArray[2].charAt(0)` should work fine, it will read first character from string placed in `inputArray` at index `2`.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2864740 already suggested, using regular expressions would be the best solution.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Here you have the Java API for Regex in particular Pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

This example shows how Patterns should be used.